# StartsWith() in an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Basically I am using the values  'hhh' to retrieve my file. I have different field starting with 'hhhh' so I cannot base my if statement on this specific field. What I would like is to to do is map and retrieve the field with hhhh...something like this

```
values[startWith('hhhh')]
```

so then I will be able to check if the field starts with hhhh and then I will be able to differentiate the field depending on the type of each field(file, text ...)

Here is what I have as an example so you can understand. It seems that I cannot inject the startsWith() inside the array like this. Any clue on how to achieve this ?

```
    const test =Object.entries(values['hhhhh']).map((entry, key) =>( {
            test: entry[0],
            test2:key
    }))
```

Comment: User this `Array.filter` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 0):

An idea can be

1. to filter the object key that match your expectation
2. loop with array.forEach method on these filtered keys
3. doing your map method on values[filteredKey]

```js
const values = {
  FLD_STR_101: {
    test: 1,
    type: 'type1'
  },
  FLD_STR_102: {
    test2: 1,
    type: 'type1'
  },
  FLD_STR_103_NO_TYPE: {
    test2: 1
  },
  NOTFLD_STR_102: {
    test3: 1
  }
};

let test = [];

Object.keys(values)
  .filter(key =>  key.startsWith('FLD_STR_') && values[key]['type'])
  .forEach(filteredKey => {
    test = [
       ...test, 
       ...Object.entries(values[filteredKey]).map((entry, key) => ({
         test: entry[0],
         test2: key
       }))]
    });

console.log(test);
```

Comment: yes this is what I need, perfect. I want to add one more thing. I want to filter with startswith('FLD_STR_). But actually I want to filter with 'FLD_STR_' and also check if it has a property of 'type'. Can I filter with two options ?  can I add 'value[0].startsWith('FLD_STR_') && value[0].hasOwnProperty('type')'

Comment: I added in my reply a  check to filtered only object that has a property type

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there, you **can** use an "startWidth" method, but not directly, try combining with the array method [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), it's cleaner and readable.

```
const values = {
  FLD_STR_101: {
    test: 1
  },
  FLD_STR_102: {
    test2: 2
  },
  INVALID_STR_103: {
    test3: 3
  }
};
const startWith = (str, prefix) =>  {
  return str.slice(0, prefix.length) === prefix;
}

const test = Object.entries(values)
  .filter(([key]) => startWith(key, 'FLD_STR_'))
  .map((entry, key) =>( {
    test: entry[0],
    test2:key
  }))
```